# Mousedown on generated Picturebox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

So, I have some code like this:

```
Dim box As PictureBox = New PictureBox
Dim Y As Integer
Dim X As Integer
Dim RandomClass As New Random()


Private Sub enspawn_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enspawn.Tick
    For pos = 30 To 100
        Y = RandomClass.Next(530)
        X = RandomClass.Next(980)
        box.Location = New Point(X, Y)
    Next pos
    box.Size = New Size(60, 60)
    box.Image = VB.NET_Game___1st.My.Resources.Resources.bittenfleax
    Controls.Add(box)
End Sub
```

So basically this will generate random picture boxes around the screen. However, how would I go about making it so when it is clicked (Mouse_Down) it does something.

I do not really have a clue how to approach this. Would it be something along the lines of:

```
If box_MouseDown Then
    MsgBox("Mouse has been pressed on the image box") 
End If
```

I am really unsure. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

If it was what I thought it was, would I create a new Private Sub to put it in? Or would it be in Form_Load?

Comment: Look into AddHandler.. for AddressOf ....picturebox.Click ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic controls for need an AddHandler statement to point it's events to a Sub. None of those variables need to be class level. Saves you from holding memory when you don't need to.

```
Private Sub enspawn_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enspawn.Tick
  Static RandomClass As New Random
  Dim box As New PictureBox
  box.Location = New Point(RandomClass.Next(980),RandomClass.Next(530))
  box.Size = New Size(60, 60)
  box.Image = VB.NET_Game___1st.My.Resources.Resources.bittenfleax
  AddHandler box.MouseDown, AddressOf box_MouseDown
  Controls.Add(box)
End Sub

Private Sub box_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
   ' sender is the PictureBox object
   Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess my comment wasnt enough .. durp... ;)